# How to set array index in a XPATH expression in python lxml package

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to search a large XML using python 'lxml' library.

The structure of the XML is :

```
<doc>
    <content>
    ....
        <facet myattr="12">
        <path>abc</path>
        <path>abc</path>
        <keyword>
        Abcdef ghijk ...
        </keyword>
    </facet>
    <facet myattr="34">
        <path>abc</path>
        <path>abc</path>
        <keyword>
        klsjdcsid llssoeo iie ...
        </keyword>
    </facet>
    .....
    </content>
</doc>
```

I am trying to retrieve the attribute "myattr" value of element "facet" where
 the child element "path" text value is "abc".

The problem is there can be many element "path" who can have the same value "abc"

So, when I try this:

```
from lxml import etree

f='..../mine.xml'

tree = etree.parse(f)

r = tree.xpath('/doc/content.../facet/path[text()=\'abc\']')

sentenceLengths = []

for x in r[:]:
    sentenceLengths.append(x.getparent().xpath('@myattr'))

# print(len(r))
print(sentenceLengths[:20])
```

It find the information I need, but they are repeated for each repeatation of element "path" with value "abc" for the same "facet" element

I tried:

```
r = tree.xpath('/doc/content.../facet/path[text()=\'abc\'][0]')
```

But it did not work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate `facet` node initially instead of locating `path` nodes and then handle parent node:

```
sentenceLengths = tree.xpath('/doc/content.../facet[path="abc"]/@myattr')
```

Comment: Works! Thank you.